# How to check if the argument to a macro is a specific string?

Tags: macros, conditionals, strings, token-lists

I need to be able to pass `[ ]` (brackets with space in between) to a `\def` and check whether the `\def`'s parameter contains `[ ]` (rather than something else).

```
\begin{document}
\def\bptoks{[ ]}
\def\bpdef#1
 { \ifx#1\string\bptoks % DOESN'T WORK
     square brackets
   \else
     something else
   \fi
 }
\bpdef{[ ]} % OUTPUT: something else
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

`\bptoks` won't expand at `\ifx`, so I tried `\ifx\detokenize{#1}\detokenize{[ ]}` but it's wrong again. I think it's because `\ifx` checks a single token and I have no clue how to make it check a token list instead. Also, `\detokenize{#1}` would probably treat `#1` as a string (I don't know).

Comment: You might also take a look at `\@ifnextchar[{true}{false}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\ifx` compares two tokens without expansion, so if you pass `[ ]` to `\bpdef`, the `\ifx` test will compare `[` with a space and fail. You need to define a temporary macro and compare it with `\bptoks`. Alternatively you can use `\pdfstrcmp` (or the equivalent in other engines (`\pdf@strcmp` if you load `pdftexcmds`)) to make a string comparison:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\makeatletter
\let\bpstrcmp\pdf@strcmp
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\bptoks{[ ]}
\def\bpdef#1%
 {%
   \def\bptmpa{#1}%
   \ifx\bptmpa\bptoks % DOESN'T WORK
     square brackets
   \else
     something else
   \fi
 }
\bpdef{[ ]}\par % OUTPUT: square brackets
\bpdef{] [}\par % OUTPUT: something else
\def\bpdef#1%
 {%
   \ifnum\bpstrcmp{#1}{\bptoks}=0
     square brackets
   \else
     something else
   \fi
 }
\bpdef{[ ]}\par % OUTPUT: square brackets
\bpdef{] [}\par % OUTPUT: something else
\end{document}
```

Remember also that `\ifx` compares *tokens*, not characters, so if you define `\bptoks` in one catcode setting and change the catcode of either `[`, , or `]` when you use `\bpdef`, the `\ifx` test will fail as well. Try this:

```latex
\catcode`\[=12
\def\bptoks{[ ]}
\catcode`\[=1
\bpdef{[ ]} % OUTPUT: something else
```

---

Additionally, your definition was:

```latex
\def\bpdef#1
  { ... }
```

this is the same as:

```latex
\def\bpdef#1 { ... }
```

which requires that when using the `\bpdef` macro you *must* put a space after the  first argument, so `\bpdef{[]} \par` would work, but `\bpdef{[]}\par` wouldn't. I added a `%` to remove that.

---

Regarding the last paragraph in your question: Yes, `\ifx` does't expand, as I already mentioned, and this implies that when you do `\ifx\detokenize{#1}\detokenize{[ ]}`, the `\ifx` compares `\detokenize` and `{` and yields false. But no, `\detokenize{#1}` would acually be `\detokenize{<actual-argument>}`. The parameter replacement takes place when `\bpdef` is expanded, and the expansion of `\detokenize` making `#1` (which was already replaced by `[ ]` or whatever) only happens later on.

Answer (score 2):

*(This is part 1 of my answer which consists of two parts. [Here is a link to part 2 of my answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500654/118714))*

---

You can implement such testing by means of delimited arguments also.

With tests based only on delimited arguments, no `\if`-switches are applied, thus such tests cannot be fooled by unbalanced `\else` or `\fi` or `\endcsname` and the like.

With tests based only on delimited arguments, no temporary assignments take place/no temporary macros get defined while they are carried out. Thus they also work in expansion contexts, i.e., they also work inside `\edef` or when carried out from within a `\csname..\endcsname`-construct.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument contains no exclamation mark which is not nested 
%% in braces:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                         {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                           contains no exclamation mark>}%
%%                         {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                           contains exclamation mark>}%
%%
\newcommand\UD@GobbleToExclam{}\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  \UD@SpaceInBracketsFork grabs the first undelimited argument behind a
%%  token-sequence of pattern  !![ ]! and removes everything between that
%%  undelimited argument and a following sequence !!!! .
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@SpaceInBracketsFork{}
\long\def\UD@SpaceInBracketsFork#1!![ ]!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument consists only of the token-sequence [ ]:
%%   In expansion-contexts the check delivers the result after exactly two
%%   expansion-steps/after exactly two "hits" by \expandafter.
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherSpaceInBrackets[1]{%
  \romannumeral0% <- romannumeral is used only for triggering expansion until
                %    in the end finding a space token trailing the `0` and thus
                %    finding a non-positive number and thus - after nicely doing
                %    a lot of expansion-work - silently not delivering any token
                %    at all.
  \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{#1}{%
    \UD@SpaceInBracketsFork
    %Case #1 is empty/has no tokens:
      !#1![ ]!{\UD@secondoftwo{}{\expandafter} \UD@secondoftwo}%
    %Case #1 = [ ]
      !!#1!{\UD@secondoftwo{}{\expandafter} \UD@firstoftwo}%
    %Case #1 = something else without exclamation-mark:
      !![ ]!{\UD@secondoftwo{}{\expandafter} \UD@secondoftwo}%
      !!!!%
  }{%
    %Case #1 = something else with exclamation-mark:
    \UD@secondoftwo{}{\expandafter} \UD@secondoftwo
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\bpdef[1]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherSpaceInBrackets{#1}{square brackets}{something else}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

1) \verb*|\bpdef{[ ]}|: \bpdef{[ ]}

2) \verb*|\bpdef{ [ ]}|: \bpdef{ [ ]}

3) \verb*|\bpdef{[ ] }|: \bpdef{[ ] }

4) \verb*|\bpdef{ [ ] }|: \bpdef{ [ ] }

5) \verb*|\bpdef{}|: \bpdef{}

6) \verb*|\bpdef{bla}|: \bpdef{bla}

7) \verb*|\bpdef{!![ ]!!!!!!}|: \bpdef{!![ ]!!!!!!}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**By the way:** Using this kind of thing you can check for several different token sequences simultaneously:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument contains no exclamation mark which is not nested 
%% in braces:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                         {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                           contains no exclamation mark>}%
%%                         {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                           contains exclamation mark>}%
%%
\newcommand\UD@GobbleToExclam{}\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  \UD@FlowersFork grabs the first undelimited argument behind a
%%  token-sequence of pattern
%%  !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!
%%  and removes everything between that undelimited argument and a following sequence !!!! .
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@FlowersFork{}
\long\def\UD@FlowersFork#1!!%
   Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!%
   Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
   #2#3!!!!{#2}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Fork whether argument either is empty or is "Rose" or is "Lily" or is "Tulip" 
%% or is "Orchid" or is "Carnation" or is "Hyacinth" or is "Peruvian Lily" or is
%% "Chrysanthemum" or is "Gladiolus" or is "Anemone" or is "Daffodil" or is "Sunflower"
%% or is something else without exclamation-mark or is something else with exclamation-mark.
%%
%%   In expansion-contexts the forking-mechanism delivers the result after exactly two
%%   expansion-steps/after exactly two "hits" by \expandafter.
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\Flowerfork[1]{%
  \romannumeral0% <- romannumeral is used only for triggering expansion until
                %    in the end finding a space token trailing the `0` and thus
                %    finding a non-positive number and thus - after nicely doing
                %    a lot of expansion-work - silently not delivering any token
                %    at all.
  \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{#1}{%
    \UD@FlowersFork
    !#1!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is empty.}%
    !!#1!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Rose''.}%
    !!Rose!#1!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Lily''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!#1!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Tulip''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!#1!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Orchid''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!#1!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Carnation''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!#1!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Hyacinth''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!#1!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Peruvian Lily''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!#1!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Chrysanthemum''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!#1!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Gladiolus''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!#1!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Anemone''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!#1!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Daffodil''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!#1!%
    { Case: Argument is ``Sunflower''}%
    !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
    { Case: Argument is something else which does not contain an exclamation mark.}%
    !!!!%
  }{ %
    Case: Argument is something else which does contain some exclamation mark(s).%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

01) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Rose}|: \Flowerfork{Rose}%

02) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Lily}|: \Flowerfork{Lily}%

03) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Tulip}|: \Flowerfork{Tulip}%

04) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Orchid}|: \Flowerfork{Orchid}%

05) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Carnation}|: \Flowerfork{Carnation}%

06) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Hyacinth}|: \Flowerfork{Hyacinth}%

07) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Peruvian Lily}|: \Flowerfork{Peruvian Lily}%

08) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Chrysanthemum}|: \Flowerfork{Chrysanthemum}%

09) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Gladiolus}|: \Flowerfork{Gladiolus}%

10) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Anemone}|: \Flowerfork{Anemone}%

11) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Daffodil}|: \Flowerfork{Daffodil}%

12) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Sunflower}|: \Flowerfork{Sunflower}%

13) \verb*|\Flowerfork{Something else without exclamation marks}|: \Flowerfork{Something else without exclamation marks}%

14) \verb*|\Flowerfork{!!Something else with exclamation marks}|: \Flowerfork{!!Something else witht exclamation marks}%

15) \verb*|\Flowerfork{ }|: \Flowerfork{ }%

16) \verb*|\Flowerfork{}|: \Flowerfork{}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*(This is part 1 of my answer which consists of two parts. [Here is a link to part 2 of my answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500654/118714))*

Answer (score 2):

*(This is part 2 of my answer which consists of two parts. [Here is a link to part 1 of my answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500653/118714))*

---

By now the tokens that are to be delivered in the different cases were "hardwired" in the macro-definition.

But you can combine such delimited-argument-based forking-mechanisms with mechanisms for grabbing the k-th element of a list of undelimited arguments and thus provide the possibility of specifying the tokens to be delivered in each case by means of a macro argument for each case:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Keep only the K-th of L consecutive undelimited arguments.
%%   ( IF K < 1 OR K > L just remove L consecutive undelimited arguments. )
%%=============================================================================
%% \KeepKthOfLArguments{<integer number K>}%
%%                     {<integer number L>}%
%%                     <sequence of L consecutive undelimited arguments>
%%
%% If L < 1 yields nothing.
%% Else:
%%   If K >= 1 and K <= L  yields:
%%     <K-th undelimited argument from <sequence of L consecutive undelimited 
%%      arguments>>
%%   If K < 1 or K > L
%%     (-> there is no K-th argument in the
%%         <sequence of L consecutive undelimited arguments> )
%%   yields nothing  but removal of <sequence of L consecutive 
%%          undelimited arguments>
\newcommand\KeepKthOfLArguments[2]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  % #2: <integer number L>
  \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsKSmallerOneFork
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000\expandafter}%
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#2 000}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsKSmallerOneFork[2]{%
  % #1: <K letters m>
  % #2: <L letters m >
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% K is smaller than one:
    \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#2}{ }{}%
  }{% K is not smaller than one:
    \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter{%
      \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
    }{%
      \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop{#1}{#2}%
    }{#2}%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop[4]{%
  % #1: <K letters m>  
  % #2: <L letters m>
  % (For detecting whether K>L or K<=L, during the loop letters m will
  %  be removed both from #1 and #2 until at least one of these arguments 
  %  is empty.
  %  When the loop terminates with 0<K<=L, #1 will be empty and #2
  %  will hold an amount of letters m corresponding to the the 
  %  difference L-K.
  %  When the loop terminates with K>L, #1 will not be empty and #2
  %  will be empty.
  % )
  % #3: <K-1 letters m>
  % #4: <L letters m>
  % (#3 and #4 will be left untouched during the loop so they can be 
  %  used for performing appropriate action when loop terminates as
  %  it is known whether K>L.)
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{% We have K<=L:
     \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{%
       #3%
      }{%
       \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#2}{ }%
      }{}%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{% We have K>L:
      \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{#4}{ }{}%
    }{% We don't know yet whether K<=L or K>L, thus remove letters m and 
      % do another iteration:
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter{%
        \UD@firstoftwo{}#2%
      }{%
        \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsEvaluateLMinusKDifferenceLoop
        \expandafter{%
          \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
        }%
      }{#3}{#4}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments{<N letters m>}%
%%                                        {<argument 1>}%
%%                                        {<argument 2>}%
%%                                        <sequence of consecutive 
%%                                         undelimited arguments>
%%.............................................................................
%% Removes the first N undelimited arguments from the <sequence of 
%% consecutive undelimited arguments>, then inserts  
%% <argument 1><argument 2>
%%
%% On the one hand when providing <argument 2> empty, you can use 
%% <argument 1> for nesting calls to \UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments.
%% On the other hand you can provide a <space token> for stopping
%% \romannumeral-expansion as  <argument 1> and have the
%% macro grab the <K-th undelimited argument> from the <sequence of L 
%% consecutive undelimited arguments> as <argument 2>.
%%
\newcommand\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments[3]{%
  %% #1: <N letters m>  
  %% #2: <Argument 1>   
  %% #3: <Argument 2>
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{#2#3}{%
    \UD@firstoftwo{%
      \expandafter\UD@KeepKthOfLArgumentsRemoveNArguments
      \expandafter{%
        \UD@firstoftwo{}#1%
      }{#2}{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% End of code for \KeepKthOfLArguments.
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument contains no exclamation mark which is not nested 
%% in braces:
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                         {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                           contains no exclamation mark>}%
%%                         {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                           contains exclamation mark>}%
%%
\newcommand\UD@GobbleToExclam{}\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Fork whether argument either is "Rose" or is "Lily" or is "Tulip" or is 
%% "Orchid" or is "Carnation" or is "Hyacinth" or is "Peruvian Lily" or is
%% "Chrysanthemum" or is "Gladiolus" or is "Anemone" or is "Daffodil" or is
%% "Sunflower" or is empty or is something else.
%%
%% \Flowerfork processes 15 arguments. The syntax is:
%%
%% \Flowerfork{<argument to check>}% <- argument 1
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Rose">}% <- argument 2
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Lily">}% <- argument 3
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Tulip">}% <- argument 4
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Orchid">}% <- argument 5
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Carnation">}% <- argument 6
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Hyacinth">}% <- argument 7
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Peruvian Lily">}% <- argument 8
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Chrysanthemum">}% <- argument 9
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Gladiolus">}% <- argument 10
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Anemone">}% <- argument 11
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Daffodil">}% <- argument 12
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "Sunflower">}% <- argument 13
%%            {<tokens in case argument is "empty">}% <- argument 14
%%            {<tokens in case argument is something else>}% <- argument 15
%%
%% In expansion-contexts the forking-mechanism delivers the result after exactly
%% two expansion-steps/after exactly two "hits" by \expandafter.
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\Flowerfork[1]{%
  \romannumeral% <- romannumeral is used only for triggering expansion...
  \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\KeepKthOfLArguments{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{#1}{%
      \UD@FlowersFork
      !#1!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {13}%<-Case: Argument is empty.
      !!#1!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {1}%<-Case: Argument is "Rose".
      !!Rose!#1!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {2}%<-Case: Argument is "Lily"
      !!Rose!Lily!#1!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {3}%<-Case: Argument is "Tulip"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!#1!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {4}%<-Case: Argument is "Orchid"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!#1!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {5}%<-Case: Argument is "Carnation"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!#1!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {6}%<-Case: Argument is "Hyacinth"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!#1!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {7}%<-Case: Argument is "Peruvian Lily"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!#1!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {8}%<-Case: Argument is "Chrysanthemum"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!#1!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {9}%<-Case: Argument is "Gladiolus"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!#1!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {10}%<-Case: Argument is "Anemone"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!#1!Sunflower!%
      {11}%<-Case: Argument is "Daffodil"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!#1!%
      {12}%<-Case: Argument is "Sunflower"
      !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
      {14}%<-Case: Argument is something else which does not contain an exclamation mark.
      !!!!%
    }{14}%<-Case: Argument is something else which does contain some exclamation mark(s).%
  }{14}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  \UD@FlowersFork grabs the first undelimited argument behind a
%%  token-sequence of pattern
%%  !!Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!
%%  and removes everything between that undelimited argument and a following sequence !!!! .
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@FlowersFork{}
\long\def\UD@FlowersFork#1!!%
   Rose!Lily!Tulip!Orchid!Carnation!Hyacinth!Peruvian Lily!%
   Chrysanthemum!Gladiolus!Anemone!Daffodil!Sunflower!%
   #2#3!!!!{#2}%
\makeatother

% Paper and vertical layout of this example:
\expandafter\ifx\csname pdfpageheight\endcsname\relax\else
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname pageheight\endcsname\relax\else
  \pageheight=\paperheight
  \pagewidth=\paperwidth
\fi
\textheight=\paperheight
\advance\textheight by -5cm
\topmargin=2.5cm
\advance\topmargin by -1in
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\footnotesep=1cm
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\footnotesize

\begin{verbatim}
\Flowerfork{Lily}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Rose''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Lily''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Tulip''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Orchid''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Carnation''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Hyacinth''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Peruvian Lily''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Chrysanthemum''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Gladiolus''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Anemone''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Daffodil''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Sunflower''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is empty.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is something else.}%
\end{verbatim}
yields:
\Flowerfork{Lily}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Rose''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Lily''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Tulip''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Orchid''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Carnation''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Hyacinth''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Peruvian Lily''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Chrysanthemum''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Gladiolus''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Anemone''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Daffodil''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Sunflower''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is empty.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is something else.}%

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\begin{verbatim}
\Flowerfork{Whatsoever / something else}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Rose''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Lily''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Tulip''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Orchid''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Carnation''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Hyacinth''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Peruvian Lily''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Chrysanthemum''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Gladiolus''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Anemone''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Daffodil''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Sunflower''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is empty.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is something else.}%
\end{verbatim}
yields:
\Flowerfork{Whatsoever / something else}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Rose''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Lily''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Tulip''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Orchid''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Carnation''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Hyacinth''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Peruvian Lily''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Chrysanthemum''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Gladiolus''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Anemone''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Daffodil''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is ``Sunflower''.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is empty.}%
           {Tokens in case argument is something else.}%

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\newpage
\begin{verbatim}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \Flowerfork{Rose}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Rose''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Lily''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Tulip''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Orchid''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Carnation''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Hyacinth''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Peruvian Lily''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Chrysanthemum''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Gladiolus''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Anemone''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Daffodil''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Sunflower''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is empty.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is something else.}%
}%
\end{verbatim}
yields:
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\test
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \Flowerfork{Rose}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Rose''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Lily''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Tulip''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Orchid''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Carnation''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Hyacinth''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Peruvian Lily''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Chrysanthemum''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Gladiolus''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Anemone''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Daffodil''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is ``Sunflower''.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is empty.}%
             {Tokens in case argument is something else.}%    
}%
\texttt{\string\test: \meaning\test}%

\noindent\null\hrulefill\null

\begin{verbatim}
\newcommand*\MyRoseCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyRoseCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyLilyCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyLilyCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyTulipCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyTulipCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyOrchidCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyOrchidCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyCarnationCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyCarnationCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyHyacinthCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyHyacinthCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyPeruvianLilyCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyPeruvianLilyCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyChrysanthemumCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyChrysanthemumCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyGladiolusCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyGladiolusCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyAnemoneCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyAnemoneCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyDaffodilCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyDaffodilCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MySunflowerCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MySunflowerCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyEmptyCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyEmptyCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MySomethingElseCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MySomethingElseCommand}.}%
\end{verbatim}

\newcommand*\MyRoseCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyRoseCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyLilyCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyLilyCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyTulipCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyTulipCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyOrchidCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyOrchidCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyCarnationCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyCarnationCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyHyacinthCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyHyacinthCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyPeruvianLilyCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyPeruvianLilyCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyChrysanthemumCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyChrysanthemumCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyGladiolusCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyGladiolusCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyAnemoneCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyAnemoneCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyDaffodilCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyDaffodilCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MySunflowerCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MySunflowerCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MyEmptyCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MyEmptyCommand}.}%
\newcommand*\MySomethingElseCommand{This comes from \texttt{\string\MySomethingElseCommand}.}%

\begin{verbatim}
\csname My\Flowerfork{Tulip}%
       {Rose}{Lily}{Tulip}{Orchid}{Carnation}{Hyacinth}{PeruvianLily}{Chrysanthemum}%
       {Gladiolus}{Anemone}{Daffodil}{Sunflower}{Empty}{SomethingElse}Command\endcsname
\end{verbatim}
yields:

\csname My\Flowerfork{Tulip}%
       {Rose}{Lily}{Tulip}{Orchid}{Carnation}{Hyacinth}{PeruvianLily}{Chrysanthemum}%
       {Gladiolus}{Anemone}{Daffodil}{Sunflower}{Empty}{SomethingElse}Command\endcsname

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

*(This is part 2 of my answer which consists of two parts. [Here is a link to part 1 of my answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500653/118714))*